# How do I get all the data in for loop in map of map in go?

Tags: go

```
package main

type Stream struct {
    Labels  string
    Entries []Entry
}

type Entry struct {
    Timestamp time.Time
    Line      string
}
```

now I have created a map of chunks

```
chunks := make(map[string]*Stream)
```

I am sending one test data and trying to form my chunks here

```
for _, line := range Lines {
    fmt.Println(line.Logmsg) // if I do print here I am getting all the data here 
    chunks["label"] = &Stream{
        Labels: "label"
        Entries: []Entry{
            Timestamp: time.Now(),
            Line:      line.Logmsg
        },
    },
}

fmt.Println(chunks)
```

I am seeing the last data in the for loop here.

I  am not seeing all the data compared to first println, is there anything I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

All insertions in the map are under the same key `"label"`, so in the end the map will only contains one element.

Either use a different label for each element or use a slice.

Comment: you mean slice in Entry ?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the stream to the same map key "label" for all lines:

```
chunks["label"] = &Stream{...}
```

Therefore the last line will always overwrite the previously set value. That is why you always only see that last line.

In order for the chunks in the end containing all data, you need to use some kind of dynamic key in this map. Something like:

```
chunks[line.Label] = &Stream{...}
```

I don't know your data so I can't tell which property you could use from line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what if I want a static value in chunks key field?

Comment: Then maybe chunks["label"] needs to be an array of Streams, so you can append multiple Stream objects.